# Error connecting to docker daemon (does docker ps work?)

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-daemon

I wanted to create a docker bench with basic setup and I use the basic code given at the [Github](https://github.com/docker/docker-bench-security) link for **Docker Benche Security**. The code is as follows :

```
docker run --rm --net host --pid host --userns host --cap-add audit_control \
    -e DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=$DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST \
    -v /etc:/etc:ro \
    -v /usr/bin/containerd:/usr/bin/containerd:ro \
    -v /usr/bin/runc:/usr/bin/runc:ro \
    -v /usr/lib/systemd:/usr/lib/systemd:ro \
    -v /var/lib:/var/lib:ro \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro \
    --label docker_bench_security \
    docker/docker-bench-security
```

But I am getting an error saying

> Error connecting to docker daemon (does docker ps work?)

Anybody has through solution for this with steps ?

Thank you very much in advance

**Docker Version :**

Client: Docker Engine - Community

- Cloud integration: 1.0.7
- Version:           20.10.2
- API version:       1.41
- Go version:        go1.13.15
- Git commit:        2291f61
- Built:             Mon Dec 28 16:14:16 2020
- OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
- Context:           default
- Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community

- Engine:
- Version:          20.10.2
- API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
- Go version:       go1.13.15
- Git commit:       8891c58
- Built:            Mon Dec 28 16:15:28 2020
- OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
- Experimental:     false
- containerd:
- Version:          1.4.3
- GitCommit:        269548fa27e0089a8b8278fc4fc781d7f65a939b
- runc:
- Version:          1.0.0-rc92
- GitCommit:        ff819c7e9184c13b7c2607fe6c30ae19403a7aff
- docker-init:
- Version:          0.19.0
- GitCommit:        de40ad0

**Linux Kernel Version** : 3.1.6-340.x86_64

[image: Error connecting to Docker Daemon]

Comment: So did you try what was suggested?  What does `docker ps` give you?  If it doesn't work, then you've got something wrong with your Docker setup.  Maybe you just don't have your environment set to use a healthy Docker environment.  You might try `docker context show`, especially if you have multiple Docker environments, and might have one of them powered down.  That's often what leads to this problem.  When faced with a problem in connection with a complex command like yours, it's best to fall back to simpler operations to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Docker ps works for me. Because I use "docker run -itd <Image Name> to start a container first. Then I try to implement the code. So "docker ps" gives me the list of the running containers.

Comment: Glancing at the repository, it's just a couple of shell scripts; I'm not sure why it's packaged in Docker, given how much host access it requires.  Can you run it with `sudo` directly on the host?  (Are you trying to develop this, or just run a prepackaged application?)

Comment: Yup. I tried working with `sudo`. It still did not work.
I am just trying to run a prepackaged application. If I wanted to develop, I might not have faced this issue.

Answer (score -1):

The problem occurs in the shell script `docker-bench-security.sh` that runs inside the container when you start it.  Here's the block of code in question, which appears to be an early sanity check:

```
# Ensure we can connect to docker daemon
if ! docker ps -q >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  printf "Error connecting to docker daemon (does docker ps work?)\n"
  exit 1
fi
```

I'm on a Mac, and I get the same error doing simply:

```
docker run docker/docker-bench-security
```

so it has nothing to do with any of your parameters.  I'm fairly new to Docker, and have never tried utilizing the docker command from inside a container, so I'm of no help here.  I googled a bit, looking for an answer.  I didn't find one.  I found a few GitHub posts asking about the same problem, but no answers ever arrived on those threads:

> https://github.com/docker/docker-bench-security/issues/197

> https://github.com/docker/docker-bench-security/issues/123

Maybe someone will come along here and give you a better answer.  I hope so.  If not, there are some clues in these threads as to where you might want to look next for an answer.